# How can I make angular create items in an array with the use of data binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my model I have a complext object graph and would like for angular to build branches as the user inputs data.  This does work as long as the property path does not contain an array.  Is there a way to get angular to create the array and add an item to it when it?

demo controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.deal ={};

});
```

This works

```
<input type="text" ng-model="deal.BorrowerSet.0.Borrower.Name"  />
```

and produces an object

```
{
  "BorrowerSet": {
    "0": {
      "Borrower": {
        "Name": "Bob"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when an array is used this does not work.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="deal.BorrowerSet[0].Borrower.Name"  />
```

I would like the following result

```
{
  "BorrowerSet": [
    {
      "Borrower": {
        "Name": "Bob"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I would like angular to build the object graph the same way it does for

http://plnkr.co/KiwjyG

Comment: This isn't a very clear question, could you take a moment to rewrite it?

Comment: It's not designed to work that way. For arrays you should use ng-repeat, and edit for each item in array. If you do not need this use nested objects like your other examples.